# Java sockets sending data repeatedly

Tags: java, sockets

Im trying to make Battleship game that works over LAN as a homework. The problem is that i need to learn myself how sockets in java work. All i need is to send Integers and use them, then return some value that informs other player of how he scored.

Client (Player 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int number, temp;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1342);
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Number: ");
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        number = sc.nextInt();          
        p.println(number);
        temp = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

}
```

Server (Player 2):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int number = 0, temp;
    ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1342);
    Socket ss = s1.accept();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        number = sc.nextInt();
        temp = number * 2;
        p.print(temp);
        System.out.println(""+temp);
    }
}
```

I would like to send 10 number and receive them back multiplied by 2. I can easilly change it to do actual calculations for the game but I need to learn how sockets work.

I had it working without the for loop but now the problem is that I dont get any number returned even though Server send it. Client receives it after Server application is canceled.

Comment: In the server, `p.print(temp);` prints the numbers with no white space between them. Try `p.println(temp);`

Comment: Yes, you are right but my problem is that client does not receive single one of the calculations and i cant send more because it is waiting for the first one to complete cycle.

Comment: The problem is due to the error noted by @JohnnyMopp, but given your current client code the fix is to append a space to each number.

Comment: Thanks it worked!